# M1 Max: Frequent panics doing a certain operation

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

If I'm uploading firmware to a usb device (which I'm developing software/firmware for) using a tool called `nrfutil` it sometimes hangs and fan speed goes up, I then have to power cycle. The devkit is connected through USB using a Caldigit TS3+ but I had the same issue with other, simpler dongles.

It sometimes won't crash for multiple hours, but sometimes it gets in a "state" where it will crash every third or fifth upload.

This has been happening for over 6 months now, currently on Monterey 12.6.

Attaching the crash report:

```
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffe001bc0dc60): [iokit.IOCommandGate]: element modified after free (off:72, val:0xffffffffffffff00, sz:80, ptr:0xfffffe2ae6f2a8f0)
   72: 0xffffffffffffff00
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x1
OS release type: User
OS version: 21G115
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:19:52 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 39A7E336B0FAA0022B3764E49DFF29D2
Kernel UUID: 778CC57A-CF0B-3D35-8EE8-5035142D0177
iBoot version: iBoot-7459.141.1
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000013ad8000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe001aadc000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001429c000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe001b2a0000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x0000000014384000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe001b388000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1850305f600a
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x63400429 0x000c3573
  Sleep   : 0x63566a72 0x0003e213
  Wake    : 0x63566b7f 0x000024a3
  Calendar: 0x6356ef05 0x0002b2b3

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xfffffe1ae2450000 - 0xfffffe3ae2450000
  . VM    : 0xfffffe1ae2450000 - 0xfffffe1faf11c000
  . RO    : 0xfffffe1faf11c000 - 0xfffffe2148ab4000
  . GEN0  : 0xfffffe2148ab4000 - 0xfffffe2615780000
  . GEN1  : 0xfffffe2615780000 - 0xfffffe2ae244c000
  . GEN2  : 0xfffffe2ae244c000 - 0xfffffe2faf118000
  . GEN3  : 0xfffffe2faf118000 - 0xfffffe347bde4000
  . DATA  : 0xfffffe347bde4000 - 0xfffffe3ae2450000
  Metadata: 0xfffffe3ae2460000 - 0xfffffe3aea460000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffe3aea460000 - 0xfffffe3af5e80000

CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 8 PVH locks held: None
CORE 9 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffe001ba5a270, LR=0xfffffe001bad833c, FP=0xfffffe45de3eb8a0
CORE 1: PC=0x00000001baad0ebc, LR=0x00000001baad0410, FP=0x000000016ba3f010
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe001ba5a288, LR=0xfffffe001bad95d8, FP=0xfffffe45de033d60
CORE 3 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe001ba87b10, LR=0xfffffe001ba87af8, FP=0xfffffe45dd93bd20
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe001b417254, LR=0xfffffe001b417254, FP=0xfffffe45df77bf00
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe001b417258, LR=0xfffffe001b417254, FP=0xfffffe45dde6bf00
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe001b417258, LR=0xfffffe001b417254, FP=0xfffffe45de88bf00
CORE 8: PC=0xfffffe001b51bfb4, LR=0xfffffe001b51bfb0, FP=0xfffffe45df8dbe90
CORE 9: PC=0xfffffe001b417258, LR=0xfffffe001b417254, FP=0xfffffe45debabf00
Compressor Info: 15% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 12% of segments limit (OK) with 1 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xfffffe2fafb28cf0: 730 pages, 7 threads: pid 327: configd
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe2613a61140, backtrace: 0xfffffe45ded4ad80, tid: 9403572
          lr: 0xfffffe001b3e1400  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4adf0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b3e10c8  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4ae60
          lr: 0xfffffe001b52733c  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4ae80
          lr: 0xfffffe001b5190cc  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4aef0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b516cb0  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4afb0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b38f7f8  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4afc0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b3e0d4c  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4b360
          lr: 0xfffffe001b3e0d4c  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4b3d0
          lr: 0xfffffe001bc0954c  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4b3f0
          lr: 0xfffffe001bc0dc60  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4b8a0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b44d318  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4b900
          lr: 0xfffffe001bb1cb84  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4b920
          lr: 0xfffffe001bb1d364  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4b950
          lr: 0xfffffe001db3b104  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4ba60
          lr: 0xfffffe001dafdd24  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bab0
          lr: 0xfffffe001bad1260  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bb20
          lr: 0xfffffe001bb66568  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bba0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b4e71c4  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bbf0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b3e7864  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bc90
          lr: 0xfffffe001b3b92a8  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bcf0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b3d44d0  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bd80
          lr: 0xfffffe001b50bd98  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4be50
          lr: 0xfffffe001b517040  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bf10
          lr: 0xfffffe001b38f7f8  fp: 0xfffffe45ded4bf20
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[888EC533-FE5A-37AD-ABEB-19EB81755978]@0xfffffe001da91a90->0xfffffe001db4759b
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[93A5E39B-72F5-3616-BE25-3C94CC232881]@0xfffffe001c8c7e90->0xfffffe001c8f7ebb
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[FAB9B01D-7434-35FB-BD7B-2FA3BD191F81]@0xfffffe001cd3a3c0->0xfffffe001cd3f4d7
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties(1.2)[EF773770-7BF7-3BFB-8FBE-6B3697C011CB]@0xfffffe001db977d0->0xfffffe001db98373

last started kext at 26724444837484: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xfffffe001b26cd40, size 5926)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver  5450.8
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 4.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.UVCService    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostBillboardDevice    1.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  456.140.3
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 5450.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelI210Ethernet 2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.filesystems.lifs  1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1934.141.2
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  583.100.10
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L84Audio  550.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSN012776Amp   550.3
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   140.1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  3.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleT6001PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleEventLogHandler   1
com.apple.driver.AppleProResHW  177.0.0
com.apple.AGXG13X   190.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   566
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  560.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispT600X-DCP   140.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCDP29XXUpdateSupport 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSerialShim    1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptControllerV2 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8110DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T600x   160.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000 1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   126.141.2
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   402
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kec.AppleEncryptedArchive 1
com.apple.driver.driverkit.serial   6.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1040.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   1040.3
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.serial 6.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  416.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   340.2
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   228.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 5450.8
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    5460.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  5460.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.5.1
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   5460.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5460.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    5460.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   550.3
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  150.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 550.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    140.2
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13XRTBuddy    190.22
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  190.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 35.29
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer  1
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.81
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT600xPCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2b2
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL    1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T600x    640.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 140.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    6.51.2
com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface   17.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    1040.3
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    597
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  9.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.16.0
com.apple.iokit.CSRBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport  9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    533.120.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  210.120.3
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   456.140.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   456.140.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleANELoadBalancer   5.68.2
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   5.68.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIISController 140.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAudioClockLibs    140.1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   302.14
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  4.2.0
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    12.0



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 714505 (Uncompressed 1916256) **
```

Comment: You test this on m1 to know it’s only on max? Not pro nor normal m1?

Comment: @JamesRisner not really, not sure if it will change the result. Maybe the subject should be changed to `M1:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was fixed in Ventura (13.0)